# Finite abelian group and GCD.

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $(G , .)$ be a finite abelian group and m∈N . Prove that $S = \{g \in G|(o(g), m) = 1\} \le G$.

I have tried via following approach:

Clearly, $e$ belongs to $S$, as $o(e)=1$ and $(o(e),m) = 1$ for any $m$ belonging to $N$.

Therefore,$S$ is non-empty.

Let $h , g$ belong to $S$. Then $(o(h),m)=1$ and $(o(g),m)=1$ but how is it true that $(o(gh),m)=1$?

For this to be true, $(o(g),o(h))$ must be equal to $1$. But it may happen in this case that these two orders may not be coprime. In that case what must be the course of action?

Comment: Think again about "For this to be true, (o(g),o(h)) must be equal to 1".

Answer (score 2):

> Let $h , g$ belong to $S$. Then $(o(h),m)=1$ and $(o(g),m)=1$ but how is it true that $(o(gh),m)=1$?

Let $a = o(h)$ and $b = o(g)$. Since $(a,m) = (b,m) = 1$, then $(ab,m) = 1$. Now $(gh)^{ab} = g^{ab}h^{ab} = (g^a)^b (h^b)^a = 1$, so $o(gh)$ divides $ab$. Therefore, $(o(gh),m) = 1$.